# Dynamically add an Android canvas?

Tags: android

I want to dynamically add my canvas to my layoiut but this has the error:
Description Location    Resource    Path    Type
The method addView(View) in the type ViewGroup is not applicable for the arguments (Canvas)     Java Problem

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.addView(canvas);
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the method 'draw' by sending the canvas like

```
l1.draw(canvas);
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be something fundamentally wrong with your question. You don't actually "add a canvas" to a view.
You use the canvas to draw in a view (ie. SurfaceView) by overriding the onDraw method.

Have a look at this blog, how the canvas can be used in Android:
[http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2010/11/drawing-with-canvas-in-android-renewed.html][1]